# Определить букву, встречающуюся чаще всего и количество её повторений. Если таких несколько вывести ту что раньше по алфавиту

Tags: c#

В основном, я выполнил задачу, но вывести ту что по алфавиту раньше не получается. Помогите пожалуйста

```
        {
            string str = "morgana liliput katarakta fartuna sueta sleep";
            int max = 0;
            string symbol = "z";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) 
            {
                int check = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
                {
                    if(str[i].ToString() == " "){continue;}
                    if (str[i] == str[j])
                    {
                        check++;
                    }
                    if (check > max)
                    {
                        max = check;
                        symbol = str[i].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Cамая часто встречающаяся буква <<{symbol}>> она повторяется {max} раз");
        }
```

Comment: Заведите массив счетчиков и используйте код буквы как индекс

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string result = "morgana liliput katarakta fartuna sueta sleep"
    .Where(z => char.IsLetter(z))
    .GroupBy(z => z)
    .OrderBy(c => c.Key)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count())
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(z => z.Value)
    .Last()
    .ToString();
```

Comment: можно чуть проще `char theBest = "morgana liliput katarakta fartuna sueta sleep".ToList().GroupBy(z => z).OrderBy(c => c.Count()).ThenBy(x=>x.Key).Select(x=>x.Key).First();` - ну и количество повторений не сохранилось

Comment: но вообще конечно для таких задач обычно ожидается оптимальное по скорости и памяти решение, а через linq реешение будет не оптимальным.

Comment: @tym32167, изменил.
Не знаю чем linq не оптимален, только если в этом случае как-то

Comment: @tym32167 - но Ваше решение, без сомнения, очень КРАСИВО!

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо 

Comment: @Yotic оно не оптимальное в моменте, где надо делать сортировку. Сортировка занимает nlog(n) операций, а простой поиск максимума - операция линейная.

Comment: хм, да, вы правы

Comment: Ну ещё, судя по заданию, надо фильтровать только латинские буквы в нижнем регистре и не учитывать пробел, например. В таких случаях обычно массив на 26 элементов делают и пишут туда счетчики повторений. Например, если буква a повторяется 5 раз, то в массиве под индексом 0 будет число 5.

Comment: Сделал, смысле обычно? 

Comment: Да это просто стандартная задача для начинающих решать алгоритмические задачки :)

Comment: Принцип можно тут подглядеть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1356512/179763

Comment: Если надо будет пример накидать тегните  меня так @tym32167 - иначе меня не уведомляет о комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто добавить свой компаратор и Linq-запрос уменьшиться в разы и станет намного эффективнее, чем код @Yotic.

Компаратор:

```
public class LettersComparer : IComparer<IGrouping<char, char>>
{
    public int Compare(IGrouping<char, char>? x, IGrouping<char, char>? y)
    {
        if (x is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));

        if (y is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(y));
    
        if (x.Count() == y.Count()) // если количество символов одинаковое - "большим" из них счиатется тот, что раньше по алфавиту
        {
            if (x.Key == y.Key)
                return 0;
            else if (x.Key < y.Key)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        else if (x.Count() > y.Count())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Код:

```
var text    = "morgana liliput katarakta fartuna sueta sleep";
var letters = text.Where(symbol => char.IsLetter(symbol));

if (letters.Any())
{
    var result = letters
        .GroupBy(letter => letter)
        .MaxBy(group => group, new LettersComparer())!;

    var letter = result.Key;
    var count  = result.Count();

    Console.WriteLine($"Наиболее повторяемая буква - {letter} ({count} повторений).");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"В заданном тексте нет букв.");
}
```